# CPP Trying to Write HEX to an executable file

Tags: file, hex

Here's my code so far:

```cpp
ofstream myfileWrite;
myfileWrite.open(myFileName, ios::binary ios::out | ios::in);
myfileWrite.flags(ios_base::hex);


const char* rawData = myHexString;
int len = sizeof(rawData);
//for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
//{
    myfileWrite.write(rawData, len);
//}
myfileWrite.close();
```

My problem is it keeps writing to the binary part of the executable rather then the actual hex itself:

```
0x4D,0x5A,0x90,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0x00,0x00
```

I'm using the above format for the actual HEX in an `EditTextBox` which is referenced as `myHexString` like so:

```cpp
GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, IDC_EDITTXT2, myHexString, sBuffer);
```

I've been at this now for a couple of days, and I've tried "unsigned char" an "reinterpret_cast" I know these are all valid uses, but I can' seem to get the `HEX` to write properly.

I'm using Windows as well just to clarify.